# How to write a unified filter iterator in c++

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I need to write my own iterator class that will act as a filter. In the iterator constructor, I need to pass the iterator of the STL container and the function object that defines the filtering criterion.
How should such a class be implemented?

I tried to write a template class that inherits from the passed iterator. However, there is an obvious problem. Trying to interact with my iterator object (+=, -= etc) I can't get the iterator's new value.

Here is the class I wrote

```
template<class Iter, class FilterFunction>
class CustomIterator: public Iter{
    FilterFunction func;
    Iter iter;
public:
    CustomIterator(Iter iter) : iter(iter) {}

    typename Iter::value_type operator*() {
        if ( func(*iter) )
            return *iter;
        return ' ';
    };
};
```

Here is the program I am trying to run

```
class IsEven {
public:
    bool operator()(int num) {
        if (num % 2 == 0) return true;
                          return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<int> vec = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    
    for (CustomIterator<vector<int>::iterator, IsEven> iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter)
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This solution is wrong, but I have no idea how to implement such a class, other than just overloading all possible operators

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Pick inheritance or composition, but don't try to use both at the same time.  Right now, a `CustomIterator` _is a_ `Iter` and it also _has a_ `Iter`, but they're different `Iter` objects.  The `CustomIterator`'s inherited members will work on the `Iter` that the `CustomIterator` _is_, but you overloaded `operator*` works on the one that it _has_.

Comment: sounds like you're reinventing `std::` views! Is that your intention?

Comment: Inheriting from `Iter` is not a good idea. A `int*` is an iterator (and it's possible that your `vector<int>::iterator` is actually just an `int*`)  - but you can't inherit from it. Sidenote: Your `IsEvent` operator should simply be `bool operator()(int num) const { return num % 2 == 0; }`

Comment: This isn't really a *filter* iterator, this is a *transform* iterator

Comment: Also I would recommend a `static_assert(std::is_convertable_v<declval(func(*iter)),Iter::value_type>)` in your destructor, so you get a clearer error message if the function doesn't accept the right type, or doesn't return the right type.

(Destructors can access the variables easier, and are ~always instantiated)

Comment: @MilesBudnek, 
If implemented through composition, as I understand it, I will need to overload all possible operators for the iterator. And if implemented through inheritance, then how can I get the value stored in my iterator in order to apply a filter function to it?
I do not understand how I need to interact with the data of my class when inheriting.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @zrow `**this` will get the value of the iterator on which you called a member function.  You should not use inheritance for this though, for the reason that @TedLyngmo pointed out in his comment.  And yes, if you use composition you'll need to create wrappers for all of the iterator operators.  Creating generic iterator wrappers in C++ is non-trivial.  Unless you're doing this as a learning exercise you should probably just prefer `for (auto i : vec | std::views::filter(IsEven{})) {...}`.

Comment: Not providing the iterator object access to the end iterator of the container will result in undefined behavior of the increment operator, since that operator needs to move the wrapped iterator forward until a match is found or the end is reached, but without knowing about the end iterator when moving on from the last match your iterator would have to move past the end...

Comment: You have not to use inheritance and composition of Iter at the same time. In this case, you should prefer the composition and then implement wrapper member functions to allow increment and decrement operations, since they may be provided for the type Iter but not for your custom iterator. Also, if you want to support all categories of iterators, you should make some member functions conditionally enabled if the underlying iterator supports them (for example, use C++20's concepts or std::enable_if to enable `operator--()` if and only if Iter is at least a bidirectional iterator).